# Crop Image issue when image size small then outer view and user zoom that image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, crop

I have face problem with crop image when original image size smaller than specific crop class view like (300,300) and user zoom that image at that time that time crop image get smaller not get exact (300,300).Here below i have added code :

## [image: Actual image in view]

[image: small image like 64 by 64 zoom]

## [image: What i get after zoom small image i need (300,300)]

## Class  @interface CropImage : UIScrollView

```
 #import "CropImage.h"


#define kMaxZoomScale 15 // Edited 3.0
#define kMinimumZoomScale 0.5

@implementation CropImage
{
    UIImageView *imgView;

}



- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        // IMAGEVIEW main
        CGRect imgFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,300); // inital size
        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imgFrame] ;
        [imgView setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
        [imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [imgView setClipsToBounds:YES]; // Edited
        [self addSubview:imgView];

        [self setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [self setDelegate:self];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
        [self setBounces:YES];

        self.minimumZoomScale = kMinimumZoomScale;
        self.maximumZoomScale = kMaxZoomScale;
    }

    return self;

}


-(void)setImageForCrop:(UIImage *)image
{
    [imgView setImage:image];
    CGSize sizeCal;

    if (image.size.height > imgView.frame.size.height || image.size.width > imgView.frame.size.width) {
        sizeCal = [self getCGSizeAspectFitRatio:image.size withBoundImageSize:imgView.frame.size];
    }
    else
    {
         sizeCal = [self getCGSizeAspectFitRatio:image.size withBoundImageSize:image.size];
    }

    float x = ((self.frame.size.width/2)-(sizeCal.width/2));
    float y = ((self.frame.size.height/2)-(sizeCal.height/2));
    [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, sizeCal.width,sizeCal.height)];

    [self setContentSize:imgView.frame.size];
}

#pragma mark 
#pragma mark - CGSIZE UTILITY 
-(CGSize) getCGSizeAspectFitRatio:(CGSize) aspectRatio withBoundImageSize:(CGSize)boundingSize
{
    float mW = boundingSize.width / aspectRatio.width;
    float mH = boundingSize.height / aspectRatio.height;
    if( mH < mW )
        boundingSize.width = boundingSize.height / aspectRatio.height * aspectRatio.width;
    else if( mW < mH )
        boundingSize.height = boundingSize.width / aspectRatio.width * aspectRatio.height;
    return boundingSize;
}

#pragma mark SCROLL VIEW DELEGATE

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale{



}
//return a view that will be scaled.
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imgView;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    [self centerScrollViewContents:scrollView];
}

- (void)centerScrollViewContents:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    @try
    {
        CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;
        CGRect contentsFrame = imgView.frame;

        if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
            contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
        }
        else {
            contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
        }

        if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
            contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
        } 
        else {
            contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
        }

        imgView.frame = contentsFrame;


        //This logic is for smaller images with size < scrollview size
        UIView *subView = [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

        CGFloat offsetX = (scrollView.bounds.size.width > scrollView.contentSize.width)?
        (scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;

        CGFloat offsetY = (scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height)?
        (scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;

        subView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX,
                                     scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"centerScrollViewContents %@",exception);
    }
    @finally
    {

    }
}


#pragma mark
#pragma mark - CROP IMAGE
-(UIImage *)getCropImage
{
    if (imgView.frame.size.width <= self.frame.size.width && imgView.frame.size.height <= self.frame.size.height)
    {
        //This code execute when we zoom out the image(small image then scroll view)
        UIImage *imagetest =[self adjustForImageViewSmallInScroll:imgView targetSize:imgView.frame.size withCGPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
        NSLog(@"SmallInScroll  Shot %@",NSStringFromCGSize(imagetest.size));

        return imagetest;
    }
    else
    {
//        CGSize sizeOriginal= imgView.image.size;
//        CGSize sizeToCrop;
//        CGPoint offsetToCrop;
//        float widthCrop = (sizeOriginal.width*self.frame.size.width)/imgView.frame.size.width;
//        float heightCrop = (sizeOriginal.height*self.frame.size.height)/imgView.frame.size.height;
//        sizeToCrop = CGSizeMake(widthCrop, heightCrop);
//        
//        NSLog(@"size to Crop from image : %@",NSStringFromCGSize(sizeToCrop));
//        
//        // Offset to crop
//        float xPointCrop = (sizeOriginal.width*self.contentOffset.x)/imgView.frame.size.width ;
//        float yPointCrop = (sizeOriginal.height*self.contentOffset.y)/imgView.frame.size.height;
//        offsetToCrop = CGPointMake(xPointCrop, yPointCrop);
//        
//        CGRect rectCrop ;
//        rectCrop = CGRectMake(offsetToCrop.x,offsetToCrop.y,sizeToCrop.width,sizeToCrop.height);
//        
//        float scale = 1.0f/self.zoomScale;
//        //ORIGNAL CODE JM  END//
//        CGImageRef imgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imgView.image.CGImage, rectCrop);
//        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef scale:scale orientation:0];
//        CGImageRelease(imgRef);
//        return img;

//        
        CGRect Fi_iv = [self frameForImage:imgView.image inImageViewAspectFit:imgView];

        //Frame ImageView in self.view coordinates
        CGRect Fiv_sv = imgView.frame;

        //Frame Image in self.view coordinates
        CGRect Fi_sv = CGRectMake(Fi_iv.origin.x + Fiv_sv.origin.x
                                  ,Fi_iv.origin.y + Fiv_sv.origin.y,
                                  Fi_iv.size.width, Fi_iv.size.height);
        //ScrollView offset
        CGPoint offset = self.contentOffset;

        //Frame Image in offset coordinates
        CGRect Fi_of = CGRectMake(Fi_sv.origin.x - offset.x,
                                  Fi_sv.origin.y - offset.y,
                                  Fi_sv.size.width,
                                  Fi_sv.size.height);

        CGFloat scale = imgView.image.size.width/Fi_of.size.width;

        //the crop frame in image offset coordinates
        CGRect Fcrop_iof = CGRectMake((self.frame.origin.x - Fi_of.origin.x)*scale,
                                      (self.frame.origin.y - Fi_of.origin.y)*scale,
                                      self.frame.size.width*scale,
                                      self.frame.size.height*scale);

        UIImage *image = [self image:imgView.image cropRect:Fcrop_iof];
        // Use this crop image...
        return image;
    }
}

//Use this code to crop when you have the right frame
-(UIImage*)image:(UIImage *)image cropRect:(CGRect)frame
{
    // Create a new UIImage
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, frame);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return croppedImage;
}
-(CGRect)frameForImage:(UIImage*)image inImageViewAspectFit:(UIImageView*)imageView
{
    float imageRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height;

    float viewRatio = imageView.frame.size.width / imageView.frame.size.height;

    if(imageRatio < viewRatio)
    {
        float scale = imageView.frame.size.height / image.size.height;

        float width = scale * image.size.width;

        float topLeftX = (imageView.frame.size.width - width) * 0.5;

        return CGRectMake(topLeftX, 0, width, imageView.frame.size.height);
    }
    else
    {
        float scale = imageView.frame.size.width / image.size.width;

        float height = scale * image.size.height;

        float topLeftY = (imageView.frame.size.height - height) * 0.5;

        return CGRectMake(0, topLeftY, imageView.frame.size.width, height);
    }
}
-(UIImage *)adjustForImageViewSmallInScroll:(UIImageView *)imgViewAdj targetSize:(CGSize)sizeTarget withCGPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGRect scaledImageRect;

    CGSize tempSize = [self getCGSizeAspectFitRatio:imgViewAdj.image.size withBoundImageSize:sizeTarget];
    scaledImageRect = CGRectMake(point.x,point.y, tempSize.width, tempSize.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scaledImageRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, scaledImageRect);
    [imgViewAdj.image drawInRect:scaledImageRect];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSLog(@"Image size  %@ ",NSStringFromCGSize(img.size));

    return img;
}
-(UIImage *)getCropImageSecond
{
    return [self cropImage:imgView.image inImageView:imgView scrollView:self];
}


-(UIImage*)cropImage:(UIImage*)image inImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView scrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView{
    // get visible rect from image scrollview
    CGRect visibleRect = [scrollView convertRect:scrollView.bounds toView:imageView];
    UIImage* rCroppedImage;

    CALayer* maskLayer= [[CALayer alloc] init];

    maskLayer.contents= (id)image.CGImage;
    maskLayer.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, visibleRect.size.width, visibleRect.size.height);

    CGRect rect= CGRectMake(visibleRect.origin.x / image.size.width,
                            visibleRect.origin.y / image.size.height,
                            visibleRect.size.width / image.size.width,
                            visibleRect.size.height / image.size.height);
    maskLayer.contentsRect= rect;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(visibleRect.size);

    CGContextRef context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [maskLayer renderInContext:context];

    rCroppedImage= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return rCroppedImage;
}
```

Comment: Could you have another stab at rewording the question - it's not entirely clear what you are asking

Comment: Let me explain in steps :
1) Selected 64*64 image from phone library.
2) set that image in crop with create ineer image view with this size .
UIImage veiw size 64*64
3) User Zoom that image more then outer view .
4) Then user press crop image 
5) crop image give small image not give image in outer view size that show in screen after zoom . basic problem is selected image is too small and user zoom that image so that i received small image but i need outer view size of image in crop..... in this scenario  .
Let me know your thoughts @Paul.s

Comment: Could you post the whole class? Much easier to play around with it and see it in action

Comment: Hi @Paul.s i have edited my question with class code . Look at it once.

Comment: So I'm guessing the actual cropping is `image:cropRect:`? If so then this will indeed just cut a portion of the original image. If you then want to scale it up you'll need to render this into a new image at the larger size

Comment: In one scenario original image size is greater then  in image:cropRect: function no need to render it . So how can i decided that this image need to render ,it will not proper as per view ? @Paul.s

Comment: Just make a method that redraws at the full size. You can add a guard clause that checks if the current image size will be the same as the target size and if so just return the original image

Comment: instead of cropping the photo, y don't u take screenshot ?

Comment: if user select small landscape image and if i will take screen shot then in crop image show white space. @Mr.T